# Print a XPS file from a byte stream

Tags: c#, .net, xps, printqueue

I want to print a XPS file in C#. I'm getting the XPS file as a byte stream. I tried to achieve this with different `AddJob` methods provided in `PrintQueue` class and encountered following issues

- `AddJob(String)`

This accepts a byte stream and do the printing. But this method keeps the file spooling for a long time so cannot use this.

- `AddJob(String, PrintTicket)`

This required a physical file location of the XPS file. since my file is a byte stream cannot use this one

- `AddJob(String, String, Boolean)`

This method also requires a physical file location

- `AddJob(String, String, Boolean, PrintTicket)`

Requires a physical file location

Therefore **how can I print a XPS file from a byte stream**. I don't want to use any 3rd party library for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following overload:

**AddJob**() - Inserts a new (generically named) print job, whose content is a Byte array, into the queue.

Some Sample code as obtained from MSDN is as follows

```
// Create the printer server and print queue objects
LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
PrintQueue defaultPrintQueue = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();

// Call AddJob
PrintSystemJobInfo myPrintJob = defaultPrintQueue.AddJob();

// Write a Byte buffer to the JobStream and close the stream
Stream myStream = myPrintJob.JobStream;
Byte[] myByteBuffer = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes("This is a test string for the print job stream.");
myStream.Write(myByteBuffer, 0, myByteBuffer.Length);
myStream.Close();
```